# Call a custom phtml file in ajax layer popup

Tags: magento

I have a custom .phtml file that I want to call in an AJAX layer (lightbox) onclick, how can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make your controller in `app/code/local/MyNameSpace/MyModuleName/controllers`

Then call that controller action in ajax call, in my case;

```
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_view')
       ->setData('product',$product)
       ->setTemplate('catalog/product/quickview.phtml');
echo $block->renderView();
```